# SEGFAULT occurs in DevC++ but not in other compilers

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, dev-c++

I had to build a 2d tree for 2d points. While inserting a node I am checking if tree already contains the same point. This gives a SEGFAULT in DevC++ but the same code runs fine in any other compilers.

Code required to rerun.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

//INPUT 0.6 0.5 0.4 0.3 0.8 0.6 0.1 0.4 0.6 0.9
#define VERTICAL 1
#define HORIZONTAL 0
int size = 0;
typedef struct point2d {
    double x;
    double y;
}point; 

typedef struct KdTree {
    point pt;
    int division;
    struct KdTree *left,*right;
}Node;

bool isLessThan(point node,point root,int division) {
    return  division == VERTICAL ? node.x < root.x : node.y < root.y;
}
int getDivisionByNode(Node *node) {
    return node->division == VERTICAL ? HORIZONTAL : VERTICAL;
}
bool equals(point p, point q) {
    return (p.x==q.x && p.y == q.y );
}
```

The SEGFAULT occurs while accessing `current->pt` in the following function. Don't know why `if(current==NULL)` is being skipped in DevC++ if there is a NULL.

```
bool contains(Node *root,point p) {
    Node *current = root;
    while(true){
        if(current == NULL){
            return false;
        }
        if(equals(current->pt,p)) //SEGFAULT
            return true;
        if(isLessThan(p,current->pt,current->division)) //SEGFAULT
         current = current -> left; 
        else 
        current = current->right;
    }
}
```

The other insert functions are as follows:

```
Node* insertNode(Node *node,Node *parent){
    if(parent==NULL){
        node->division = VERTICAL;
        return node;
    }
    if(isLessThan(node->pt,parent->pt,parent->division)) {
        if(parent->left == NULL) {
            node->division = getDivisionByNode(parent);
            parent->left = node;
        }
        else
            parent->left = insertNode(node,parent->left);
    }
    else {
        if(parent->right == NULL) {
            node->division = getDivisionByNode(parent);
            parent->right = node;
        }
        else
            parent->right = insertNode(node,parent->right);
    }
    return parent;
}

Node* insert(Node *root, point p){
    if(!contains(root,p)){
        Node *node = malloc(sizeof(*node)); //check here
        node->pt.x=p.x;
        node->pt.y=p.y;
        root = insertNode(node,root);
        size++;
    }
    return root;
}
```

**driver code**

```
int main() {
    Node *root = NULL;
    int i;
    double x,y;
    point p;
    for ( i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        scanf("%lf %lf",&x,&y);
        p.x = x;
        p.y = y;
        root = insert(root,p);
        printf("[%f,%f]",root->pt.x,root->pt.y);
    }
}
```

What needs to be done to remove SEGFAULT and run it properly in DevC++ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are invoking *undefined behavior* by using indeterminate values of `Node`'s members `left` and `right` while they are allocated via `malloc()` and uninitialized.

Initialize them like this:

```
Node* insert(Node *root, point p){
    if(!contains(root,p)){
        Node *node = malloc(sizeof(*node)); //check here
        node->pt.x=p.x;
        node->pt.y=p.y;
        node->left=NULL; /* add this */
        node->right=NULL; /* add this */
        root = insertNode(node,root);
        size++;
    }
    return root;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. My code works now..! Can you give an idea of why other compilers do not find this as Segfault?

Comment: @Leo It's undefined behavior. The compiler would even be allowed (Following the C spec) to insert a `system("rm -rf / --no-preserve-root")` if it encounters UB.

Comment: Strictly speaking, it is _unspecified_ (not undefined) behavior to read an indeterminate value with allocated storage duration, unless the given type happens to have a trap representation on the given system. The undefined behavior here is rather the accessing the contents of a pointed-at address when the pointer has an indeterminate value.